# codeigniter autoload file issue

Tags: linux, codeigniter, codeigniter-routing

I have uploaded codeigniter file in my linux server using php version 5.5. I got issue on application\config\autoload.php file.

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array(); //default code
//$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
```

When  i  run the program using default code. program runs fine. But when i load database library, we didn't get any error or output. it shows blank page.

you can check [here](http://www.mycrushsocial.com/test/show).

Sample Code:

```
class Test extends CI_Controller {  

    function show() {   
        echo 'methos call';
    }
}
```

This program runs in my local without issue.
Is that server problem or codeignitor issue.

Thanks

Comment: try with $autoload['libraries'] = array("database", "session"); and check

Answer (score 1):

In `autoload.php` file Change

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database')
```

Then go to `database.php` and configure your database.(Bottom of page).

if CodeIgnitor 2.0.0

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = '';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
$db['default']['database'] = '';//database name
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

If CodeIgnitor 3.0.0

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => '',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => '',//database name
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => TRUE,
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

If you correct these it should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

If the code is running fine on local machine and giving problem on server please check the name of file.  It should in lowercase and the class name should in camelcase.
It worked for me please try.

Comment: This is a good point to care about but it could not be correct here because links such as "http://www.mycrushsocial.com/Test/show" or "http://www.mycrushsocial.com/Test/Show" are showing error 404 page not found.

Answer (score 0):

Try using following code,

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('html_errors', 1);
```

It will show all the errors which sometimes hidden by default.

Comment: Thanks for responding I tried both but still we are facing issue. Is it any other issue.

Comment: I tried hole day for troubleshooting. But i didn't get exactly what is the problem on loading $autoload['libraries'] = array('database');.

I found stack overflow link about this type of issue

Problem with database in CodeIgniter

Unable to auto/manually load database library in codeigniter

Please suggest if any other solution for this issue.

Comment: This would make all errors visible in a PHP page so if there is any error it will be shown, if there is nothing showing it possibly a problem with your route.php page